# Conditional sentences, mixed conditionals

Tags: conditional-constructions

> 1. If she (let's call this person X) **had** said anything to you (let's call this person Y) about her coming over to your place tonight, I would probably drop by your place as well.
> 2. If she said anything to you about her coming over to your place tonight, I would probably drop by as well.

Which of these sentences convey, **X hasn't said anything to Y about X's coming over to Y's place tonight, which is why I probably won't drop by Y's place.**, the best.

---

- *I haven't anything productive this week, I think that's why I'm depressed.*
- *If I had done something productive this week, I wouldn't so depressed.*

Do the two sentences convey the same information, that he hasn't done anything productive this week, and that he's depressed?

Answer (score 2):

If you **had asked** politely ...

> I would probably give you a cookie.
>
> I would probably have given you a cookie.

You did not ask politely, or we're just talking about a past hypothetical.

If you **asked** politely ...

> I might have given you a cookie.
>
> I might give you a cookie.

You may or may not have asked.  Requires context to know whether the speaker is talking about what has happened or about what might happen.

Comment: +1 from me  What about: "*If Alice* **had said** anything about her coming over to your place tonight, I **would have** probably drop**ped** by your place as well* " Would that also work?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: Your sentence could be understood in both ways as well. It is either a statement by the speaker implying that Alice did not say anything, or a hypothetical about what the speaker is likely to have done  if the condition in the if-clause were true.  The context of the conversation in which the statement is made tells us the speaker's intended meaning, lthough this kind of if-statement can be used to avoid making an *unconditional* statement. "Were you at the bank on the afternoon of the robbery?  --If the shop's proceeds had been deposited by my business partner, I would not ...